# Does bazel support operation behind a corporate proxy, e.g. $http_proxy env var?

Tags: bazel

While searching I have seen some questions that look similar, but all of them were in the context of building tensorflow.

I am new to Bazel and make my first attempts. I am trying to build envoyproxy. It works fine at my home PC, but it does not work in our corporate work environment where we are behind a proxy that I configured via the typical environment variables like (upper and lower case) http_proxy and https_proxy.

The Bazel build tool even tells me "WARNING: ignoring http_proxy in environment."

My theory is that it does not take the environment variable due to one of two reasons:

1. Because it operates in client/server mode, e.g. the environment variable may not have an effect on the server part. I tried this by using the --batch option. But this does not seem to work either. It tells me: "WARNING: Running Bazel server needs to be killed, because the startup options are different." and then triggers the same errors.
2. The bazel "sandboxed execution" is somehow in the way.

The concrete error with envoyproxy is: "failed to fetch com_github_golang_protobuf: # cd .; git clone https://github.com/golang/protobuf /home/cs/.cache/bazel/_bazel_cs/759903e17d9c37e2598e0572738d3485/external/com_github_golang_protobuf"

And several other git clone attempts.

So my question in short: does Bazel allow for operating with http_proxy, e.g. does it forward this environment variable to sub-processes like the git clone above?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Different plug-ins work differently.

- http - bazel seems to be working fine for this.
- git - turn the proxy settings globally.

  ```
  git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
  ```
- go repos. Haven't found a solution for them. "$got get repo.com/package" takes http_proxy environment into account, but not when launched from bazel

Comment: I've tried the git config --global idea, but it did not work for me. Not sure why?